# How to handle HttpSession in MbUnit

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a ASP.NET MVC 1.0 Controller which implements a HttpSession object for storing sorted result

How I can test the Controller from MbUnit?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a mocking framework like [Rhino Mocks](http://www.ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx) or [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) (there are even more).
Then you have to mock your session and other context objects. Scott Hanselman has a [very helpful post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCSessionAtMix08TDDAndMvcMockHelpers.aspx) on how to achieve this.

Regards.